# Firefox and internet explorer does not css render correctly?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Im having a few issues with IE and firefox css

go to http://www.chriscaplan.com/KEW/

have a look in chrome that is displaying correctly

then have a look in IE or firefox it doing some weird stuff.

is there something im doing wrong ?

can any one help???

Comment: Did you edit this yourself? Specifically the "clear:none"

.container:after,
.row:after,
.u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: none; }

Comment: i think i did as i had some difficultly with the navigation, but i just put the original skeleton.css back on the site and everything is working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 style sheets working against each other:

#### [skeleton.css](https://github.com/dhg/Skeleton)

#### style.css

Replace the `skeleton.css` with the latest version and run it in IE and you will see. I switched your version with the latest and it started to work on IE.

Comment: There are still some issues with your styling, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Your method for clearing floats is not working.

If I were you, I would take some time to look at multiple examples on live websites of how people have put together their sites' headers. Right now the structure and styles on your header don't seem to follow normal design patterns. And by normal, I mean common, well tested, typical for a reason, etc

Comment: I would give you more specific advise, but in my eyes, the question here is "How can I layout something in HTML and CSS?" and to that, I can only suggest you do research yourself.

Comment: thanks for your response, do you have any examples sites or any sources I could look at